# SELECT para filtrar valor nulo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` em uma tabela `conta`, nesta tabela tenho uma `foreign key` para a tabela `venda`, em certos casos esta `foreign key` eh nula e eu quero retornar as informacoes da venda quando esta chave nao for nula e ignorar quando for, estou tentando fazer isso através de um `left join`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Como fazer isso ?

estou tentando assim.

```
select * from conta t1
inner join cliente t2 on (t2.id = t1.cliente_id)
left join (
    select * from venda t3 
    inner join itemvenda t4 on (t4.venda_id = t3.id)
    inner join produto t5 on (t4.produto_id = t5.id)    
    ) ON ((t1.venda_id is not null) AND t1.venda_id = t3.id)
where (t1.status = 0) AND (t1.tipoConta = 1) AND (t1.dtVencimento BETWEEN "2016/10/01" AND "2016/10/28")
ORDER BY t2.nome, t1.dtVencimento
```

**Exception**

```
select * from conta t1
inner join cliente t2 on (t2.id = t1.cliente_id)
left join (
    select * from venda t3 
    inner join itemvenda t4 on (t4.venda_id = t3.id)
    inner join produto t5 on (t4.produto_id = t5.id)    
    ) ON ((t1.venda_id IS NOT NULL) AND t1.venda_id = t3.id)
where (t1.status = 0) AND (t1.tipoConta = 1) AND (t1.dtVencimento BETWEEN "2016/10/01" AND "2016/10/28")
ORDER BY t2.nome, t1.dtVencimento LIMIT 0, 25
Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Comment: faltou um `as` na parte do `left Join () as c` e continua... tem um erro de `t3` não é o alias correto seria: `) as c ON ((t1.venda_id IS NOT NULL) AND t1.venda_id = c.id)`

Comment: @Bacco aparentemente este duplicado nao aparenta ser a msm situação que preciso.

Comment: Notar que só há o fechamento efetivo se outras pessoas tiverem a mesma impressão e votarem da mesma forma, mas mesmo assim você pode sempre [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes que diferenciem mais, ou mesmo deixar um comentário para a gente saber qual foi o problema que teve com o `IS NULL`. Fechamento é ferramenta de organização, e não de penalização. A idéia é que de uma maneira ou outra você saia daqui com o problema resolvido. Mas para isso, precisa detalhar melhor a dificuldade exata, para que a gente saiba como ajudar. O 1º passo seria arrumar o Alias faltando (`AS nome`).

Comment: Sem dúvida o erro é no aliás. .. Você está tentando acessar o t3 que está dentro de outro contexto.

Comment: Eu não sei qual foi a sua lógica para fazer um left join com um sub select sendo que você não fez nenhum filtro ou selecionado somente alguns campos das tabelas, seu select poderia ter sido foito com left join direto nas tabelas sem a necessidade do su subselect...

Answer (score 1):

O bloco do left join precisa ter um alias. Modifica tua consulta adicionando um alias da seguinte forma:

```
left join (
    select * from venda t3 
    inner join itemvenda t4 on (t4.venda_id = t3.id)
    inner join produto t5 on (t4.produto_id = t5.id)    
    ) nomedoalias ON ((t1.venda_id IS NOT NULL) AND t1.venda_id = t3.id)
```

Em `nomedoalias` você modifica para o alias desejado.